# Game - collection of characters and random movement collision

Tags: list, data-structures, collections, collision

I am trying to make a simulation of a rabbit population. these rabbits are printed on a grid say 50x50 on a console app.

I have several questions which would really help.

If I want to keep a record of all the bunnehs with their individual characteristics, is a List the best way to record this data?

For random movement, I generate a random move (-1,0,+1) on the x-axis and on the y-axis. 
If i want to avoid collision against other existing rabbits, is calculating the new x,y and comparing them against the list the only way.

like:

```
foreach(Bunny bunny2 in lst)
    if (bunny2.x == newbunny.x && bunny2.y == newbunny.y) 
        then move newbunny again
```

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what you're talking about, I'd use a 2 dimensional to hold all of your bunnies. e.g.

```
Bunny[49][49] grid; //make a 2D array of bunny objects
```

This way you can have your data structure perfectly represent your system. Then you could actually use the indices (x, y) of the grid to map to the 2D array. For example this would get you the bunny at x = 3, y = 17:

```
Bunny myBunny = grid[2][16]
```

Also this would ease in collision detection, as you can just check if there is a bunny in the relevant grid space you want to move to, so if the bunny in the previous example wanted to go x-1 spaces, then you could check if that grid coordinate had a null value:

```
if(grid[1][16] == null) { //then bunny can go there
   //code to move bunny
   grid[2][16] = null //remove bunny from old grid space
} else { //buny can't go there
   //code
}
```

**NB!** In order for this to work, you need to make sure you take the bunny OUT of the grid space it is moving from, as done in the previous example. That way you maintain where there are no bunnies versus where they are.

Comment: thank you for your answer. There is one problem i can think of with grids. if i want every single bunny to move once each "turn", how would i go through each bunny once. using a nested for loop for [y] and [x] will find the same bunny again (if it moved downwards/ to the right). I think a combination of list & grid could work or add the moved bunnies to a new grid

Comment: Sure, I see what you're saying. Just keep references to the bunnies in a normal array as well, so you could make a Bunny, then store it in a 1 dimensional array (say, "bunnies"), then in a 2 dimensional array ("grid"). Then you can just loop through the one dimensional array to access each bunny, then use the grid to check where bunnies are. It has slightly higher memory overhead than a single list of bunnies, but provides quicker computation.